# Infrequent GUI hang when blindly closing the Text Editor without saving

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, gui

I often use the Text Editor for quick notes, leaving them unsaved while I track down a good place to save them.  Most of the time, I find that the same idea is already saved somewhere, and so I just close the new notes without saving, sometimes by right-clicking the taskbar and then Close.

Rarely when I do that, about 2 or 3 times a year, when it's not the topmost window when I close it, it triggers the entire screen to freeze up, except for the mouse.  It looks like the Close command does nothing, and when I switch to it, it's asking if I want to save.  Click No, the question goes away, and it hangs immediately.

The overall sequence is:

1. Open the Text Editor (leafpad), and type or paste some notes into it.
   Don't save, so there's no file behind it at all, not even an old one.
2. Open a different file in a different copy of the Text Editor.
3. Right-click on the taskbar and close the first one (while still showing the second one).
   Nothing seems to happen.
4. Click on the taskbar to show the one I was trying to close, and it's asking if I want to save.
5. Click No to not save.
   The question goes away, and the GUI locks up immediately.

I think it's still re-drawing, because the mouse moves freely and doesn't leave trails.  But nothing is clickable.  It's as if the present display, minus the mouse, has become a full-screen "dumb image" with a controllable mouse pointer still drawn on top.  And I think I can see a 1-pixel-wide indication of 100% on my realtime graph of total memory usage, when it might have been around 5% before.  (Pi 4 8GB)

At this point, both the mouse and the VNC server still work, but nothing is clickable anymore, from either source.  The only way I've found to get out of this, short of a hard reset, is the "RE" of [REISUB](http://blog.kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/).  That closes *everything*, and I can then use the mouse on the system menu to reboot normally.  I imagine that I could also reboot it via SSH, but I haven't actually tried that.

I keep it up to date about twice a week, with the usual `apt` commands, so this has happened across several versions of things in the repository, including what is current at the time of this writing.
(Aug 25 '21)

---

I've never been able to make it freeze on purpose, manually.  Follow those steps again, and it just closes like it's supposed to and the system moves on.  But I also found that I could automate it, and that gives a reliable hang in about 10 minutes maximum.  Here's the code, spread across two files:

0_script_wrapper.sh (my standard wrapper for everything):

```
#!/bin/sh

cd `dirname $0`
SCRIPT_NAME=$1
shift

#run the script that was called for, with all remaining arguments
./$SCRIPT_NAME "$@" 2>&1 | ts "%Y-%m-%d_%a_%H-%M-%S" >> ./$SCRIPT_NAME.log
```

`apt install moreutils` to get `ts`.  It puts a timestamp on every line of its stdin, and puts the result on stdout.  That's a wonderful thing to have, for many reasons!

leafpad_crash.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# To start: path/to/0_script_wrapper.sh leafpad_crash.sh
# The wrapper does 2 things:
#     - Sets the working directory to be the location of the wrapper file
#     - Redirects all output to a logfile in that location

# Manual set-up, before starting:
# Cut or Copy some text to the clipboard (Ctrl+X or Ctrl+C), and have an empty leafpad window open.
# Start as above, then refocus leafpad before this 10-second timer expires:
sleep 10

COUNT=0
while true
do
    # Incrementing count into a logfile
    COUNT=$(($COUNT+1))
    echo $COUNT

    # Assumes that there is already a leafpad window open and on top, but not necessarily focused yet
    xdotool mousemove --sync 753 600 click 1
    sleep 1
    xdotool key ctrl+v
    sleep 1

    # Open a new leafpad window from the Application Launch Bar
    xdotool mousemove --sync 420 1032 click 1
    sleep 1
    if [[ `xdotool search --classname leafpad | wc -l` -ne "4" ]]
    then
        # That click didn't do anything, must have found the failure
        # (also triggers if there are too many, which serves as an early kill method)
        echo Test Ended.
        scrot 'leafpad_crash.sh_%Y-%m-%d_%a_%H-%M-%S.png'
        exit 0
    fi

    # Try to close the previous leafpad window, that was just pasted into
    # (will ask to save first)
    xdotool mousemove --sync 810 1032 click 3
    sleep 1
    xdotool mousemove_relative --sync 0 -35 click 1
    sleep 1

    # Focus that window and answer No
    xdotool mousemove --sync 810 1032 click 1
    sleep 1
    xdotool mousemove --sync 753 590 click 1
    sleep 1
done
```

`apt install xdotool` to get that.  The `mousemove` coordinates will probably have to be adjusted to make it work on your system, but it should otherwise work as-is, provided that you have the Text Editor (leafpad) in your quick launch.  `xdotool getmouselocation` makes that adjustment easy.

Run it with `$ path/to/0_script_wrapper.sh leafpad_crash.sh`, and it creates a logfile in `path/to/leafpad_crash.sh.log`.

I renamed the logfile and ran it again a couple of times, and I got this:

leafpad_crash.sh.1.log (the first to run, and the longest):

```
2021-08-25_Wed_07-46-55 1
2021-08-25_Wed_07-47-03 2
2021-08-25_Wed_07-47-11 3
2021-08-25_Wed_07-47-19 4
2021-08-25_Wed_07-47-27 5
2021-08-25_Wed_07-47-35 6
2021-08-25_Wed_07-47-43 7
2021-08-25_Wed_07-47-51 8
2021-08-25_Wed_07-47-59 9
2021-08-25_Wed_07-48-07 10
2021-08-25_Wed_07-48-15 11
2021-08-25_Wed_07-48-23 12
2021-08-25_Wed_07-48-31 13
2021-08-25_Wed_07-48-39 14
2021-08-25_Wed_07-48-48 15
2021-08-25_Wed_07-48-56 16
2021-08-25_Wed_07-49-04 17
2021-08-25_Wed_07-49-12 18
2021-08-25_Wed_07-49-20 19
2021-08-25_Wed_07-49-28 20
2021-08-25_Wed_07-49-36 21
2021-08-25_Wed_07-49-44 22
2021-08-25_Wed_07-49-52 23
2021-08-25_Wed_07-50-00 24
2021-08-25_Wed_07-50-08 25
2021-08-25_Wed_07-50-16 26
2021-08-25_Wed_07-50-24 27
2021-08-25_Wed_07-50-32 28
2021-08-25_Wed_07-50-40 29
2021-08-25_Wed_07-50-48 30
2021-08-25_Wed_07-50-56 31
2021-08-25_Wed_07-51-04 32
2021-08-25_Wed_07-51-13 33
2021-08-25_Wed_07-51-21 34
2021-08-25_Wed_07-51-29 35
2021-08-25_Wed_07-51-37 36
2021-08-25_Wed_07-51-45 37
2021-08-25_Wed_07-51-53 38
2021-08-25_Wed_07-52-01 39
2021-08-25_Wed_07-52-09 40
2021-08-25_Wed_07-52-17 41
2021-08-25_Wed_07-52-25 42
2021-08-25_Wed_07-52-33 43
2021-08-25_Wed_07-52-41 44
2021-08-25_Wed_07-52-49 45
2021-08-25_Wed_07-52-57 46
2021-08-25_Wed_07-53-05 47
2021-08-25_Wed_07-53-13 48
2021-08-25_Wed_07-53-21 49
2021-08-25_Wed_07-53-29 50
2021-08-25_Wed_07-53-38 51
2021-08-25_Wed_07-53-46 52
2021-08-25_Wed_07-53-54 53
2021-08-25_Wed_07-54-02 54
2021-08-25_Wed_07-54-10 55
2021-08-25_Wed_07-54-18 56
2021-08-25_Wed_07-54-26 57
2021-08-25_Wed_07-54-34 58
2021-08-25_Wed_07-54-42 59
2021-08-25_Wed_07-54-50 60
2021-08-25_Wed_07-54-58 61
2021-08-25_Wed_07-55-06 62
2021-08-25_Wed_07-55-14 63
2021-08-25_Wed_07-55-22 64
2021-08-25_Wed_07-55-30 65
2021-08-25_Wed_07-55-38 66
2021-08-25_Wed_07-55-46 67
2021-08-25_Wed_07-55-54 68
2021-08-25_Wed_07-56-02 69
2021-08-25_Wed_07-56-10 70
2021-08-25_Wed_07-56-18 71
2021-08-25_Wed_07-56-26 72
2021-08-25_Wed_07-56-34 73
2021-08-25_Wed_07-56-42 74
2021-08-25_Wed_07-56-50 75
2021-08-25_Wed_07-56-58 76
2021-08-25_Wed_07-57-06 77
2021-08-25_Wed_07-57-14 78
2021-08-25_Wed_07-57-22 79
2021-08-25_Wed_07-57-30 80
2021-08-25_Wed_07-57-38 81
2021-08-25_Wed_07-57-46 82
2021-08-25_Wed_07-57-54 83
2021-08-25_Wed_07-58-02 84
2021-08-25_Wed_07-58-10 85
```

leafpad_crash.sh.2.log:

```
2021-08-25_Wed_14-16-57 1
2021-08-25_Wed_14-17-05 2
2021-08-25_Wed_14-17-13 3
2021-08-25_Wed_14-17-21 4
2021-08-25_Wed_14-17-29 5
2021-08-25_Wed_14-17-37 6
2021-08-25_Wed_14-17-45 7
2021-08-25_Wed_14-17-53 8
2021-08-25_Wed_14-18-01 9
2021-08-25_Wed_14-18-09 10
2021-08-25_Wed_14-18-17 11
2021-08-25_Wed_14-18-25 12
2021-08-25_Wed_14-18-33 13
2021-08-25_Wed_14-18-42 14
2021-08-25_Wed_14-18-50 15
2021-08-25_Wed_14-18-58 16
2021-08-25_Wed_14-19-06 17
2021-08-25_Wed_14-19-14 18
2021-08-25_Wed_14-19-22 19
2021-08-25_Wed_14-19-30 20
2021-08-25_Wed_14-19-38 21
2021-08-25_Wed_14-19-46 22
```

leafpad_crash.sh.3.log:

```
2021-08-25_Wed_15-49-20 1
2021-08-25_Wed_15-49-28 2
2021-08-25_Wed_15-49-36 3
2021-08-25_Wed_15-49-44 4
2021-08-25_Wed_15-49-52 5
2021-08-25_Wed_15-50-00 6
2021-08-25_Wed_15-50-08 7
2021-08-25_Wed_15-50-16 8
2021-08-25_Wed_15-50-24 9
2021-08-25_Wed_15-50-32 10
2021-08-25_Wed_15-50-40 11
2021-08-25_Wed_15-50-48 12
2021-08-25_Wed_15-50-56 13
2021-08-25_Wed_15-51-04 14
2021-08-25_Wed_15-51-12 15
2021-08-25_Wed_15-51-20 16
2021-08-25_Wed_15-51-28 17
2021-08-25_Wed_15-51-36 18
2021-08-25_Wed_15-51-45 19
2021-08-25_Wed_15-51-53 20
2021-08-25_Wed_15-52-01 21
2021-08-25_Wed_15-52-09 22
2021-08-25_Wed_15-52-17 23
2021-08-25_Wed_15-52-25 24
2021-08-25_Wed_15-52-33 25
2021-08-25_Wed_15-52-41 26
2021-08-25_Wed_15-52-49 27
2021-08-25_Wed_15-52-57 28
2021-08-25_Wed_15-53-05 29
2021-08-25_Wed_15-53-13 30
2021-08-25_Wed_15-53-21 31
2021-08-25_Wed_15-53-29 32
2021-08-25_Wed_15-53-37 33
2021-08-25_Wed_15-53-45 34
2021-08-25_Wed_15-53-53 35
2021-08-25_Wed_15-54-01 36
2021-08-25_Wed_15-54-09 37
2021-08-25_Wed_15-54-17 38
2021-08-25_Wed_15-54-25 39
2021-08-25_Wed_15-54-33 40
2021-08-25_Wed_15-54-42 41
2021-08-25_Wed_15-54-50 42
2021-08-25_Wed_15-54-58 43
2021-08-25_Wed_15-55-06 44
2021-08-25_Wed_15-55-14 45
2021-08-25_Wed_15-55-22 46
2021-08-25_Wed_15-55-30 47
2021-08-25_Wed_15-55-38 48
2021-08-25_Wed_15-55-46 49
2021-08-25_Wed_15-55-54 50
2021-08-25_Wed_15-56-02 51
2021-08-25_Wed_15-56-10 52
2021-08-25_Wed_15-56-18 53
2021-08-25_Wed_15-56-26 54
2021-08-25_Wed_15-56-34 55
2021-08-25_Wed_15-56-42 56
2021-08-25_Wed_15-56-50 57
2021-08-25_Wed_15-56-58 58
2021-08-25_Wed_15-57-06 59
2021-08-25_Wed_15-57-14 60
2021-08-25_Wed_15-57-22 61
2021-08-25_Wed_15-57-30 62
```

As you can see, the exit message doesn't happen.  And neither does the screenshot, which was disappointing.  But it was always locked up at that point.  Same symptoms as the accidental manual version.

Between each test, I did the RE of REISUB to recover, let the display manager restart itself, opened the File Manager (pcmanfm) to rename the logfile, and then the Terminal to run the next test.  No reboot in between.

I had the foresight to back up the SD card before starting this abuse, since *I was intentionally trying to make it crash*.  (!)  And sure enough, it started having other problems after those few tests, like my USB hard drives on a powered hub no longer being mounted correctly for one example, even after a system reboot.  Re-imaging the card from that backup fixed all of those.

---

Anyone know what's going on here?  And how to not have it crash at all when I inevitably do this aborted-note thing again?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is "how to avoid the problem or recover from it without a reboot", though I wouldn't expect to get a solution for something that can't be reliably reproduced.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, you're right.  That's fixed now.  And you're probably right about getting a solution too, but it doesn't hurt to ask.  And the description is out now, so maybe someone that knows more about the internals than I do can work on it.

Comment: @jsotola Fixed, see edit.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev my question would be `how to debug such a problem?` ... that is why I asked

Comment: @AaronD try automating the sequence of events that appear to lead to the problem ... it may be possible to reproduce the behavior more often, if the events are repeated every few seconds

Comment: @jsotola Okay...so now I'll have to look at automating the mouse and keyboard.  I've done it before on Ubuntu, so I just need to revisit that project and see how.  It'll be a few days before I get there.  If it's a rare memory leak in leafpad or in Raspbian's window manager, according to my theory so far, then that should be a valid test.

Comment: there is also a temporary file created ... it may somehow be involved

Comment: @jsotola I finally got there, like I said last week.  And I have test results!  You were right that this could be automated...but it's still expensive in the sense of breaking other things after several tests, and having to re-image the card.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Lots more info now, including an automated test that can reliably cause the problem.